# Debug print is causing stack overflow for a struct with field type std::rc::Rc

Tags: rust

I am following the linked list implementation from this [book](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-building.html).
The `List` and `Node` structs are like this -

```
type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct List<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
    tail: Link<T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    elem: T,
    next: Link<T>,
    prev: Link<T>,
}
```

I have a `push_front` method like below -

```
    pub fn push_front(&mut self, elem: T) {
        let new_node = Node::new(elem);
        let new_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node));
        let mut old_head = self.head.take();
        old_head.as_mut().map(|node| {
            node.borrow_mut().prev = Some(Rc::clone(&new_node));
        });
        new_node.borrow_mut().next = old_head.clone();
        self.head = Some(new_node);
        if self.tail.is_none() {
            self.tail = self.head.clone();
        }
    }
```

The code compiles fine. But whenever I put a debug print `List` in my test, I get a test failure with the message `thread 'tests::test_list_1' has overflowed its stack`.

```
    #[test]
    fn test_list_1() {
        let mut list = List::new();
        list.push_front(1);
        list.push_front(2);
        list.push_front(3);
        println!("{:?}", list);
        // assert!(false);
    }
```

If I comment out the `println!` line then the test passes. So basically the debug print of `list` is causing the stack overflow here. I am not able to understand why exactly.

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b8d41ef333a7b623392bdbb850b4b57) of the full code.

I have experimented with the code to find out specifically the below line is causing the problem.

```
println!("{:?}", list);
```

So my guess since `list` has a type `std::rc::Rc` and `println!` macro takes a reference of the value, it is somehow creating a cycle somewhere. I am not able to specifically identify the problem though.

Comment: My guess is you try to deference all the pointers when you print your list. Try to implement Debug trait to only track in once direction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derived `impl Debug for Node` prints both `prev` and `next`, but `prev` will try to print its next (which is the current node) and `next` will try to print its `prev` (ditto) so this is an infinite recursion.

You need to impl `Debug` manually:

```rust
impl<T: Debug> std::fmt::Debug for Node<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        f.debug_struct("Node")
            .field("elem", &self.elem)
            .field("next", &self.next)
            .finish()
    }
}
```

You can also manually impl `Debug` for `List` if you don't want to print `tail`.

Comment: I agree and this will work, but how would this solution get modified if you wanted to print the `Option` for `prev`, so that you know if it's `Some` or `None`?  So avoiding the infinite recursion, but still "for debugging purposes" being able to fully analyze it?  Maybe `.field("prev", if is_some(&self.prev) { "Some" } else { "None"})` or similar?

Comment: @KevinAnderson You need to take a reference (`if is_some(&self.prev) { &"Some" } else { &"None"})`. It can also be something like `.field("has_prev", &self.prev.is_some())`.